# Software to Explain Geometrical Construction

Tags: geometric-construction

I would like to know about a software that will help me SHOW construction of geometrical figures. Maybe something as simple as constructing a triangle. BUT I need to see a compass and a Straight Edge/Scale/Ruler in the final video.

I would then record the screen and then add it to my educational videos. So basically, I want to **explain geometrical construction** using a Compass/Straight Edge/Protractor/Divider etc.

Thank you in advance.

The video should show something like this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R70lVArbmSw

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_geometry_software) Wikipedia page has a list of interactive geometry software, and you could start looking there. Most would be fine to construct the figures, but I don't know if any of them would show you the actual instrument.